# Does it matter if used new tab or new window if I am going to use headless browser in python helium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, performance, helium

I am using helium library for web scraping dynamic websites
I found it much faster to use tabs than using many windows yet some websites when I open them in a new tab they show some ads and I could not find a way to close them. That made me look for a lot of JS codes, which I do not understand, and most of the times they are not working when executed using helium library in python even though they work fine in the Console of Google Chrome.

***However, the code should be running headless*** and I am doing all of this only for testing and here is my main question
**Does it matter if used new tab or new window if I am going to use headless browser in python helium**
is it going to be faster just like what happens when it runs normal or since it is headless it makes no difference ?

not to forget to mention that it is way easier for me to work with many windows since I won't have to use JS codes.

```
driver.execute_script('''$x('xpath')[0].remove();''')
driver.execute_script('''$x('xpath')[0].click();''')

$x('xpath')[0].remove();
$x('xpath')[0].click();

selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: $x is not defined
```

they both work just fine in Google Chrome Console but for some reason, I can not execute them python helium.
I tried using to give more time using `time.sleep(5)` to load the page but it did not work

not to mention that I tried using the `click()` method from helium it gives me a `LookupError()`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to test it for myself it might not be accurate but the results gave me a clear winner I used the windows task manager to see the percentage of CPU usage in all the cases when running headless tabs were faster and used way less CPU than new windows